# htaccess redirect to wordpress if I type domain.com/index.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've been trying to figure this out but no success. I have a static site in `domain.com/site/index.html` but I'm also creating a new wordpress version in / to eventually replace it.

What do I put in `.htaccess` so typing `domain.com` opens *www.domain.com/site/index.html* (static website) while typing `domain.com/index.php` opens the Wordpress site? Is this possible?

**Edit:** I deleted the previous .htaccess code I posted here. It just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` is just the host name (e.g. "www.domain.com").  To test the path after the host name you need to use `REQUEST_URI`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/index.php
```